# How to identify genes in Ralstonia that synthesize PHB and promote granule formation?

Tags: genetics, microbiology, dna-sequencing

The compound polyhydroxybutyrate (PHB) is of considerable industrial interest as a biodegradable substitute for plastic. PHB is synthesized from glycerol by the bacterium *Ralstonia eutropha*. PHB accumulates to high levels in proteindelimited inclusion bodies called PHB granules that are thought to protect the compound from degradation. PHB stains with the blue dye polyphorin 3Z27, so *Ralstonia* colonies on polyphorin plates have a blue color when glycerol is present (and PHB is made), but a white color if glycerol is absent (and PHB is not made).

Since bacterium *E. coli* is not able to synthesize PHB, but it would be useful to engineer an *E. coli* that does so. What approaches can I use with *E. coli* to identify the *Ralstonia* genes that synthesize PHB and promote granule formation?

Comment: As far as I can tell the original results for this kind of question were presented back in the late 80s - early 90s: [Poly-P-hydroxybutyrate (PHB) Biosynthesis
in Alcaligenes eutrophus H16](http://www.jbc.org/content/264/26/15298.long), [Cloning of the Alcaligenes eutrophus genes for synthesis of poly-beta-hydroxybutyric acid (PHB) and synthesis of PHB in Escherichia coli.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC211690/), [Molecular basis for biosynthesis and accumulation of polyhydroxyalkanoic acids in bacteria](http://femsre.oxfordjournals.org/content/9/2-4/217.long).